# Examples of Suzerainty

Tags: regulations

Under Article 2 of the ICAO (chicago) [convention](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/7300_9ed.pdf), the Territory of a State is considered to be those areas under which the state has [suzerainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzerainty) (control over the foreign policy and international affairs).

Are there any current examples of this in practice?

[image]

Comment: That is a legal term, not an aviation term.  It simply happens to appear in an aviation document.

Comment: I agree. This asks for examples of a political/international construct, not for anything aviation-related. Also, the wikipedia article already linked gives some historical examples.

Comment: question updated (current examples).  I'm interested from an aviation perspective (as it determines which jurisdiction is applicable when flying through different airspaces)

Comment: Very interesting use of the word "adjacent".  Adjacent generally means "next to" rather than "part of".  Legal clarification  may be in order.  As far as jurisdiction, this would clearly be defined by boundaries, with the exception of disputed areas.  I would certainly do homework before going there, and try to be aware of the potential dangers.  There may also be a "pecking order", such as ground control modifying flight plans as needed.  It would depend a lot on what "different airspaces" you had in mind.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but you might get a better response on [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Good examples are Monaco, under France suzerainty, or San-Marino (maybe Vatican) under Italy one's. There are lots of them.

Answer (score 1):

The ICAO is the International Civil Aviation Organization founded in 1947.  The statement "for the purposes of this convention the territory of a State shall be deemed to be the land areas and territorial waters adjacent thereto under the sovereignty, suzerainty, protection, or mandate of such State" has applications to current world issues.

Though it is understandable that some may feel this is unanswerable as a "aviation question", it is relevant and sparks interest.

Rules are made by people for people.  This wording, written over 70 years ago, may be subject to review.  Key words are "adjacent" and "sovereignty, suzerainty, protection, OR
mandate".  As with any Standard Operating Procedure, an improved version may supersede it.

If an area is in dispute, that does NOT mean rules for air space over it can not established and abided by, especially for civilian air craft. Cooperation of the parties involved is a possibility.